# How to test the effect of various manipulations of an independent variable on a dependent variable in a timeseries?

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis

I am currently monitoring the daily energy consumption of a house since January of this year. That daily consumption depends on several variables, including outdoor temperature, solar irradiance etc.

At regular intervals (once every two weeks) I am changing the algorithm of the heating controller, to see if I can improve the energy savings.

What is the methodology one should follow for testing whether such a change has any effect on a timeserie? I've found a short example in BHH2 (where they analyze the effect of a law on pollution levels) but I need a more thorough discussion.

**Update**

Here is a plot of the data I'm working with:

[image: Energy vs time]

This shows the daily energy consumption. The green line indicates when we introduced the change to the algorithm. As you can see, there already was a trend towards lower energy consumption even before we introduced the change, probably due to outdoor temperatures getting warmer. What I need to know is whether the introduction of the change has significantly accentuated that trend or not.

Note also that since that time, we have collected much more data than what is shown on this plot.

Comment: did you look at the [changepoint](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-point) tag?

Comment: @mp This isn't a changepoint problem because the times of change are exactly known.  It's really a question about regression with strongly correlated multiple measurements.

Comment: I changed the title to try to make it clearer that this is NOT a changepoint problem. Feel free to change it to something better.

Comment: @Jeromy I'm not sure I understand the title to my question any longer :-)

Comment: This would fall under the umbrella of intervention analysis; the common reference is Box & Tao 1975's JASA paper, "Invervention analysis with applications" to something or other. There's been a lot of work since then too, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion , you might need to add/detect day-of-the-week ; week-of-the-year ; Holiday effects ( lead ,contemporaneous and lag effects ); possible level shifts and or Local Time Trends ; Possible fixed-days-of-the-month; Pulses/Outlier correction via Intervention Detection schemes ; AND then INTRODUCE a set of possible predictors (K-1) reflecting EACH of the K algorithmic change effects. Additionally you might need to incorporate an ARMA component to your predictors to render your error process Gaussian. Care should also be taken to ensure that the parameters of your final model did not significantly change over time and that the residuals from your final model have constant variance. Heterogenous error variance can be caused by structural changes in variance at particular time points , coupling of the error dispersion and the level of the output series and/or a pure stochastic variance change over time.